# Why I am getting 'pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --env=qa' when running multiple pytest commands in a bash script

Tags: python, pytest

Hell there,

1.

- I am using pipenv to create and activate a virtual environment where all dependencies are installed.
- All the tests pass but my build fails because of this Error:

```
ERROR: usage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --env=qa
  inifile: /*/*/projects/<root dir>/pytest.ini
  rootdir: /*/*/projects/<root dir>
```

2. metadata: {'Python': '3.8.3', 'Platform': 'Linux-4.4.0-184-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.17', 'Packages': {'pytest': '7.2.0',...}
3. 

```
**conftest.py**:
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--env", action="store", help="Environments: qa, staging, prod")
```

4. 

**Project dir structure**

```
├── roster
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── conftest.py
│   ├── run_suite_jenkins.sh
│   ├── smoke
│   └── utils.py
```

5. 

**executable bash script has multiple such commands: **run_suite_jenkins.sh**:

```
pytest roster/smoke/tests/test_team.py --env=qa --alluredir allure-results 
pytest roster/smoke/tests/test_account_access.py --env=qa --alluredir allure-results
pytest roster/smoke/tests/test_brand.py --env=qa --alluredir allure-results
pytest roster/smoke/tests/test_company.py --env=qa --alluredir allure-results
.....
.....
.....
```

6. 

I execute the script this way: `$./roster/run_suite_jenkins.sh`

**FYI**.
I know I can run the tests with just this command, but there reasons why we are not doing it this way.

```
pytest roster/smoke/tests/ --env=qa --alluredir allure-results
```

Any help will be much much appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_addoption) explains why this is not working. It states:

> This function should be implemented only in plugins or conftest.py files situated at the tests root directory due to how pytest discovers plugins during startup.

Based on the diagram of the repository structure you are showing, the `conftest.py` file is not located in the root of the `tests` directory. Move it there and try again.